# wikicfp.xml parser python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse the wikicfp.v1.2008.xml and wikicfp.v1.2009.xml and wikicfp.v1.2010.xml. The three available versions in the link below.
https://github.com/creswick/wikicfp-parser/tree/master/data
I tried with XML.etree.ElementTree and with beautifulsoup, but I got a lot of encoding errors like

> not well-formed (invalid token): line 949, column 40
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 63563: character maps to undefined>

I couldn't progress because of the errors. I aim to parse each row and save it in a SQL script file or CSV file for later usage.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
out_file = open("final.sql","w")
out_file.write("--DROP TABLE event1;\n")
out_file.write("CREATE TABLE event1 (eventid int, fullname TEXT, location TEXT, begindate TINYTEXT , finishdate TINYTEXT , weblink TEXT, info TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (eventid));\n")
out_file.close()
infile = open("wikicfp.v1.2009.xml",encoding='utf-8-sig')
contents = infile.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents)
rows = soup.find_all('row')
c = 0
for count in rows:
    tempsoup = rows[c]
    try:
        ei = tempsoup.findAll("field", {"name":"eventid"})
        if not ei[0].contents[0].strip():
            ei = "No info"
        eventid = ei[0].contents[0].strip()

    except Exception:
        eventid = 0

    try:
        fn = tempsoup.findAll("field", {"name":"fullname"})
        s = fn[0].contents[0].strip()
        fullname = s.decode('utf-8')
        fullname = fullname.replace("'","_")
    except Exception:
        fullname = "No info"
    try:
        l = tempsoup.findAll("field", {"name":"location"})
        s = l[0].contents[0].strip()
        location = s.decode('utf-8')

        location = location.replace("'","_")

    except Exception:

        location = "No info"

    try:

        bd = tempsoup.findAll("field", {"name":"begindate"})

        s = bd[0].contents[0].strip()

        begindate = s.decode('utf-8')

    except Exception:

        begindate = "No info"

    try:

        fd = tempsoup.findAll("field", {"name":"finishdate"})

        s = fd[0].contents[0].strip()

        finishdate = s.decode('utf-8')

    except Exception:

        finishdate = "No info"

    try:

        wl = tempsoup.findAll("field", {"name":"weblink"})

        s = wl[0].contents[0].strip()

        weblink = s.decode('utf-8')

    except Exception:

        weblink = "No info"

    try:

        i = tempsoup.findAll("field", {"name":"info"})

        s = i[0].contents[0].strip()

        info = s.decode('utf-8')

        info = info.replace("'","_")

    except Exception:

        info = "No info"
    with open("final.sql","a") as out_file:
        out_file.write("INSERT INTO event VALUES (")
        out_file.write(eventid)
        out_file.write(", '")
        out_file.write(fullname)
        out_file.write("', '")
        out_file.write(location)
        out_file.write("','")
        out_file.write(begindate)
        out_file.write("','")
        out_file.write(finishdate)
        out_file.write("','")
        out_file.write(weblink)
        out_file.write("','")
        out_file.write(info)
        out_file.write("');\n")
        c=c+1
out_file.close()
infile.close()
```

another start of try 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
with open("wikicfp.v1.2009.xml") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'xml')
rows = soup.find_all('row')
```

another try

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('wikicfp.v1.2009.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

Comment: Can you show some of your attempts?

Comment: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('wikicfp.v1.2009.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

Comment: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("wikicfp.v1.2009.xml") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'xml')
rows = soup.find_all('row')

Comment: You should edit your question and add the code...

Comment: I edited theteh code. have you tried it ? any promising solution?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your xml-files are containing invalid characters. I tried sveral different text editors (Notepad++, bracket, Notepad, ...) and all of them ran into several positions, they couldn't encode properly (e.g. in the 2008-xml at the end of line 56964). So the xml-parser fails to parse the xml right there. You could use lxml and its Parsers recover-option to ignore those characters:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

tree = ET.parse('wikicfp.v1.2008.xml', 
ET.XMLParser(encoding='ISO-8859-1', ns_clean=True, recover=True))
root = tree.getroot()
rows = root.findall('row')
for row in rows:
    fields = row.findall('field')
    for field in fields:
        print(field)
```

You can get lxml by simply typing `pip install lxml` in your bash

Comment: Thank you for trying it and helping. could you please write other steps in extracting the fields texts from from a row ?. It will be more helpful.

Comment: I added iterating over rows and fields.